# why script doesnt run?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

Well i am working on a website wordpress and i want to add javascript code to the article but it doesnt run !!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Web Page</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(5 + 6);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

here the code , i tried custom field but it doesnt work also .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jV0uU.png)

[where i add the code exactly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6lN3.png)

Comment: The code runs fine for me

Comment: yep, looks to be fine... https://jsfiddle.net/jext6v0w/ something else must be up, besides your code

Comment: This works fine, but most importantly: never, ever, use `document.write`. It's from an ancient version of JS, and JS has been in the unfortunate position where it can't remove old functions. However, you should [absolutely never use it](https://pomax.github.io/1473270609919/if-you-use-use-document-write-you-suck-at-javascript). If you just want to test something, use `console.log`. And even better, do not put it in script tags, put it in a file, and load it as `<script src="url/for/your/file.js" async defer></script>`, because CSP will almost always disallow script code like this.

Comment: can you check the second photo guys ? i updated my post maybe because i am adding the code in wrong place !!

Comment: If you're adding that JS code to a WP page or post, WP will strip it out

Comment: @MohammadAlsaleh you can't add html tag or body tag inside text editor as WP loads these syntax by default from template. You should just write the code inside a div that's it. And for custom scripting you can using such plugins like Insert Header & Footer code. Anyway you can try this tutorial: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-easily-add-javascript-in-wordpress-pages-or-posts/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using gutenberg editor then you need to add custom html block to print out your script.

Check my backend screenshot: https://prnt.sc/rjqti4
Check my frontend screenshot: https://prnt.sc/rjqu3y

And if you're trying to do it on custom code then you should go for create a custom template or on single.php or on page.php file you simply use this code to load the desired items. Basically this is not the proper way to add script in WordPress though if you're using this script only on certain pages.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume wordpress is stripping it out, you may need a plugin such as https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-embed-code/#description to use script tags inside a post

Answer (score 0):

You can add javascript code inside WordPress post > "Text" tab like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
document.write(5 + 6);
console.log("Please check console: ", (5+6));
// ]]></script>
```

After adding this, save the WP post and then view the page in the browser.

Answer (score -4):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Greetings Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./first.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Greetings</h1>
  <p id="greeting">Hello, World</p>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('greeting').innerHTML = 'Hello JavaScript!';
    }, 3000);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```